# Networking question - why can't my iPad connect to the closest network?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, airport, ipados

I'm a network grasshopper, so bear with me. I have a 3 story home, with wifi routers on every floor, each has its own network. When I move from the 1st floor to the 3rd floor, my iPad never connects to the 3rd floor router, and every time I change floors I have to reconnect to the closest router for the best signal. Is there any way to avoid this? (mesh network?)

Comment: Filling in a few of the blanks in your question might be helpful. Make/model of the networking gear at the very least.

Comment: Are you expecting the closest geographically to be the best signal? Which is likely to be best based on signal path?

Comment: @Steve Chambers - 1 router is a Verizon one, the other 2 are Apple (one AirPort and one TimeCapsule)

Answer (score 0):

Because the best router for your iPad is nearly never the nearest one.
This choice is based on the signal/noise ratio your iPad "see" of your 3 routers. This environment permit your iPad to switch quickly on the
best network if all your routers are configured to the same network name
( for example : "hall of killing waves" ),,
but use different channels ( for example: 36, 40, 44 )

This signal/noise ratio decrease of course with the distance, but also
with the obstacles like walls ( concrete ones ), glasses, people, floors ( contrere ones ).

If you want to better understand this field, I advise you to install
[iStumbler](https://istumbler.net/downloads/) which is working on Yosemite → Big Sur.

Comment: Thx @dan - iStumbler looks helpful, but it's not working for > 12 from the site: The latest version of iStumbler crashes at launch on macOS Monterey
(Version 12.0.x) and is currently off-sale on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Try to motivate the author: he is pretty good.